# How to serialize form data into an object with nested properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following inputs:

```
<input name="person[1]['first']" />
<input name="person[2]['first']" />
<input name="person[3]['first']" />
```

I want to serialize this into an object like so:

```
person = {
  1: {first:value},
  2: {first:value},
  3: {first:value}
}
```

Is this functionality available in jQuery or javascript now? or will I have to write a function to do it?

Comment: The object example you have is not valid, did you mean `{ "person1": { "first": "value" }, ...}`?

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant

Comment: The issue I am getting "person[1]['first']" is being used as the entire key for any serialize function

Answer (score 0):

You can use, when it is inside `<form>` tag:

```
$(formElement).serialize();
```

Comment: This creates a string, not an object.

Comment: This will also create "person[1]['first']" as the key

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

**EDIT**

Adding short example on a form submit:

```
$('#container').on('submit', '#myForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // $(this) contains the form element
    console.log(data); // will output serialized data
    console.log(data.email); // will output email input value (if any)
});
```